# Unable to import tensorflowjs successfully

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.6, tensorflowjs

I have tensorflow 1.5 and everything is working fine with tensorflow.
Now i want to convert my tensorflow keras model to be used in web app so i installed tensorflowjs successfully but when i import i get the error.

I have tried changing the following versions:
numpy from 1.16.4 to 1.15.1,
tensorflow 1.5.0 to 1.8.0 and 1.12.0,
tensorflowjs 1.1.2 to 1.0.0

tensorflow test:

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.__version__)
hello = tf.constant("Hello Tensorflow")
with tf.Session() as sesh:
    print(sesh.run(hello))
```

Output:

```
1.12.0
2019-06-11 12:02:11.140827: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
b'Hello Tensorflow'
```

So i guess everything is fine with tensorflow but still i cant import tensorflowjs due to some files missing in my tensorflow installation.

i got this error first:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Uxama/PycharmProjects/untitled1/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflowjs as tfjs
  File "C:\Users\Uxama\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflowjs import converters
  File "C:\Users\Uxama\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflowjs.converters.tf_saved_model_conversion_v2 import convert_tf_saved_model
  File "C:\Users\Uxama\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\tf_saved_model_conversion_v2.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import convert_to_constants
ImportError: cannot import name 'convert_to_constants'
```

Then i placed the file (convert_to_constants) manually because changing the versions doesn't seems to work and change anything.

Then i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Uxama/PycharmProjects/untitled1/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflowjs as tfjs
  File "C:\Users\Uxama\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflowjs import converters
  File "C:\Users\Uxama\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflowjs.converters.tf_saved_model_conversion_v2 import convert_tf_saved_model
  File "C:\Users\Uxama\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\tf_saved_model_conversion_v2.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import convert_to_constants
  File "C:\Users\Uxama\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\convert_to_constants.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import wrap_function
ImportError: cannot import name 'wrap_function'
```

I did the same thing again and placed the file but the errors seems to kept coming.

I don't know what exactly causing the problem i installed tensorflow with pip and also tried installing it with wheels as well.
I just want to successfully install tensorflowjs so that i can convert my keras model to use in web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow 1.12 doesn't define a function called `wrap_function()`. Consider upgrading to `API r1.13`. [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.12/api_docs/python/tf#functions) are the functions defined in `API r1.12`, which you are currently using, and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.13/api_docs/python/tf/wrap_function) is the `wrap_function()` method which is defined in `API r1.13`.

Comment: After upgrading to tensorflow1.13.1 i get this error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
SystemError: <class '_frozen_importlib._ModuleLockManager'> returned a result with an error set
ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import

Comment: Please upgrade your `numpy` version to `1.16.1`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions tensorflow is working fine also i converted the model with tensorflowjs after i upgraded to numpy 1.16.1 but i wonder if that would cause any problem with tensorflowjs because of this warning that i get when i installed numpy 1.16.1
==> tensorflowjs 1.1.2 has requirement numpy==1.15.1, but you'll have numpy 1.16.1 which is incompatible.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you can ignore the warning. A similar issue has been discussed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1484).